# Sequelize failing when attempting to add one-to-one relationship between two models

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to use Sequelize to add a one-to-one relationship between two tables.

```
UsersModel.belongsTo(models.ImagesModel, { foreignKey: 'profilePictureId' })

ImagesModel.hasOne(models.UsersModel)
```

However, when starting up and attempting to create these tables, Sequelize fails with an unknown error:

```
(node:20899) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
```

I can log all of the Postgres statements made by Sequelize, however there are too many to manually sift through.

Manually adding the foreign key constraint works as expected:

```
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS image_id INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users_images FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES images (id);
```

Why is it not working with Sequelize? I have other one-to-one relationships set up with Sequelize that work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by upgrading Sequelize from ^6.21.0 to ^6.33.0.

The underlying issue is that, for some reason, adding the relationship in the question causes Sequelize to run a bunch of ALTER TABLE commands across multiple tables (not just `users` / `images`) when `.sync` is called.

Here is a small sample of the ALTER TABLE statements

```
Executing 114: ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "lastName" DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "lastName" DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "lastName" TYPE VARCHAR(255);
Executing 115: ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "accountType" DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "accountType" SET DEFAULT 'email';
CREATE TYPE "public"."enum_users_accountType" AS ENUM('google', 'apple', 'email');
ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "accountType" TYPE "public"."enum_users_accountType" USING ("accountType"::"public"."enum_users_accountType");
```

In ^6.21.0, any of these ALTER TABLE statements to do with an enum cause an unhandled error to occur, whereas with ^6.33.0 the error no longer occurs.

I'm still not sure why the ALTER TABLE commands get run in the first place though.

**UPDATE**

The ALTER TABLE commands are run because there is a cyclic dependency between tables. According to [the docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/constraints-and-circularities/) Sequelize should say

```
Cyclic dependency found. documents is dependent of itself. Dependency chain: documents -> versions => documents
```

However it never said this. Additionally, if I follow the advice and remove the underlying database constraints, the ALTER TABLE commands are still run. Instead, I am opting to break the cyclic dependency through a re-design of my database schema.